# Java annotation processor written using Gradle unable to read resources from src/main/resources

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I'm trying to create a custom annotation processor using Java on Gradle. I have a working. project set up with the processor being able to generate Java source files, etc. I am trying to read some configuration files that are going to be located in `src/main/resources` of the subproject that uses the annotation processor. Unfortunately, I have tried everything and still cannot get the processor to read files from src/main/resources.

Gradle version: 7.3
Java version: 11

If I have a file called `sub/file.txt` under `src/main/resources`, I have tried all the below combinations.

```
processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, "sub", "file.txt");
processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_OUTPUT, "sub", "file.txt");
processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "sub", "file.txt");
processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH, "sub", "file.txt");
```

And each one produces a `NoSuchFileException`. I have even tried with empty string for the middle argument and `sub/file.txt` for the last one to no avail.

I also have the below in my build.gradle

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    dependsOn tasks.processResources

    inputs.file(layout.buildDirectory.file("resources/main/sub/file.txt"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this same issue, I was finally able to read resource files from within an annotation processor after updating my `build.gradle` to include the following:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.sourcepath = sourceSets.main.resources.getSourceDirectories()
}
```

And then within the annotation processor using:

```java
processingEnv.getFiler().getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, "", "sub/file.txt");
```

Gradle version: 7.5.1

Java version: 17